# ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzwn.class

Tags: android, react-native

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzwn.class

I tried to create a task to remove a duplicate, but did not get success.

This task:

```
task findDuplicates {
    doLast {
        def findMe = 'com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzwn.class'
        configurations.compile.asFileTree.matching {
            include '**/*.jar'
        }.files.each { File jarFile ->
            zipTree(jarFile).visit { FileVisitDetails fvd ->
                if (fvd.path == findMe) {
                    println "Found $findMe in $jarFile.name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fast-image')
    compile project(':react-native-facebook-login')
    compile project(':realm')
    compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-vkontakte-login')
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    compile project(':react-native-custom-tabs')
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(':react-native-fabric')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.9.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your build.gradle file code

Answer (score 2):

I find conflict between `react-native-google-analytics-bridge` and `react-native-onesignal`, I add dependencie `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'` in `app/build.gradle`.

I hope that will help someone.

Comment: I am really very grateful. I spent several hours trying to find a solution. I had  the same problem  with the exact same dependencies and your solution works perfectly.

Comment: In my case was zzdx, but no matter. 
Man, thanks a lot, you saved my Job!!!

PD: how do you know that conflict was related to com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging ? I spend a day trying to find were was the conflict. Also android logging aren't helpfully to find it.

how do you find it?